# Improve delete with IN performance

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I struggle to write a DELETE query in MariaDB 5.5.44 database.

The first of the two following code samples works great, but I need to add a WHERE statement there. That is displayed in the second code sample.

I need to delete only rows from *polozkyTransakci* where *puvodFaktury* <> *FAKTURA VO CZ* in *transakce_tmp* table. I thought that my WHERE statement in the second sample could have worked ok with the inner SELECT, but it takes forever to process (it takes about 40 minutes in my cloud based ETL tool) and even then it does not leave the rows I want untouched.

1.

```
DELETE FROM polozkyTransakci
WHERE typPolozky = 'odpocetZalohy';
```

2.

```
DELETE FROM polozkyTransakci
WHERE typPolozky = 'odpocetZalohy'
     AND idTransakce NOT IN (
 SELECT idTransakce
 FROM transakce_tmp
 WHERE puvodFaktury = 'FAKTURA VO CZ');
```

Thaks a million for any help

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN is very bad on performance .. Try using NOT EXISTS()

```
DELETE FROM polozkyTransakci 
WHERE typPolozky = 'odpocetZalohy'
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM transakce_tmp r
                     WHERE r.puvodFaktury = 'FAKTURA VO CZ'
                          AND r.idTransakce = polozkyTransakci.idTransakce );
```

Comment: a lot of Ifs, Ands, and Buts there.. you should specify when Exist might perform better than In and vise versa and not just say "IN is very bad on performance"  I've seen in real life that IN performs better than EXISTS in a lot of cases, but i also know what NULLs can do..

Comment: I do agree that David should at least try NOT EXISTS()

Comment: Yes, and if the question was "Why is in bad on performance" or "what is better exists or in" then I would consider explaining it.. but that wasn't the question, I didn't say NOT EXISTS() would perform better then IN as you can see, I just said that IN isn't good, and he should try NOT EXISTS().. @JamieD77

Comment: Thanks guys, I was wondering about performance but I am fairly new to sql so I didn’t know that not exists could perform better. Unfortunately I don’t run the latest version of mariadb and it seems to not understand _not exists_. But I am not sure - I didn’t investigate that. I kept trying and wrote IN p<>f instead of NOT IN p=f and this seems to perform better.

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/exists.php - says there is exists function in mariadb

Answer (score 1):

Before you can performance tune, you need to figure out why it is not deleting the correct rows.

So first start with doing selects until you get the right rows identified. Build your select a bit at time checking the results at each stage to see if you are getting the results you want.

Once you have the select then you can convert to a delete. When testing the delete do it is a transaction and run some test of the data that is left behind to ensure it deleted properly before rolling back or committing. Since you likely want to performance tune, I would suggest rolling back, so that you can then try again on the performance tuned version to ensure you got the same results. Of course, you only want to do this on a dev server!

Now while I agree that not exists may be faster, some of the other things you want to look at are:

- do you have cascade deletes happening? If you end up deleting many
  child records, that could be part of the problem.
- Are there triggers affecting the delete? especially look to see if someone set one up to run through things row by row instead of as a set. Row by row triggers are a very bad thing when you delete many records. For instance suppose you are deleting 50K records and you have a delete trigger to an audit table. If it inserts to that table one record at a time, it is being executed 50K times. If it inserts all the deleted records in one step, that insert individually might take a bit longer but the total execution is much shorter.
- What indexing do you have and is it helping the delete out?
- You will want to examine the explain plan for each of your queries to
  see if they are improving the details of how the query will be
  performed.

Performance tuning is a complex thing and it is best to get read up on it in detail by reading some of the performance tuning books available for your specific database.

Comment: Thank you for cool points and ideas, I am sure I will use this someday. But I think I just found out that this problem was caused further in my Business Intelligence solution.

Answer (score 0):

I might be inclined to write the query as a `LEFT JOIN`, although I'm guessing this would have the same performance plan as `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE pt
    FROM polozkyTransakci pt LEFT JOIN
         transakce_tmp tt
         ON pt.idTransakce = tt.idTransakce AND
            tt.puvodFaktury = 'FAKTURA VO CZ'
    WHERE pt.typPolozky = 'odpocetZalohy' AND tt.idTransakce IS NULL;
```

I would recommend indexes, if you don't have them:  `polozkyTransakci(typPolozky, idTransakce)` and `transakce_tmp(idTransakce, puvodFaktury)`.  These would work on the `NOT EXISTS` version as well.

You can test the performance of these queries using `SELECT`:

```
    SELECT pt.*
    FROM polozkyTransakci pt LEFT JOIN
         transakce_tmp tt
         ON pt.idTransakce = tt.idTransakce AND
            tt.puvodFaktury = 'FAKTURA VO CZ'
    WHERE pt.typPolozky = 'odpocetZalohy' AND tt.idTransakce IS NULL;
```

The `DELETE` should be slower (due to the cost of logging transactions), but the performance should be comparable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At first I tried writing my commands using JOIN, but I believe now that the IN/EXISTS is able to work just fine.